# Replace values in a table

Tags: bash, replace, table

I have a table (ascii format with space delimiter), as follow:

```
1 1 1900 111
1 2 1900 121
1 3 1900 145
1 4 1900 1.45e 07
1 5 1900 5.21e 25
1 6 1900 152
```

I would like, that if there is a fifth column (obviously enclosing the value of the exponent) the value is replaced by 0. Therefore, considering this example, the desired output should be as follow:

```
1 1 1900 111
1 2 1900 121
1 3 1900 145
1 4 1900 0
1 5 1900 0
1 6 1900 152
```

Does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
awk '{if (NF>4){print $1, $2, $3 , "0" } else {print $0}}' INPUTFILE.txt
```

Comment: `awk 'NF>NF=4{$4=0}1' file`

Comment: @rcjohnson It actually does the trick!

Comment: Can you explain how does your awk line work, User112638726?

Comment: NF>NF=4 "in lines where the number of fields is greater than 4, set the number of fields to 4" {$4=0}1 "and set $4 to zero. Print every line processed."